# How to put additional files in package installation directory?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am writing a post installation script for a python package. For that I need to copy some files to the installation directory of the package. Is there a way to get the location after/during:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

One general solution is to do the following:

```
# post installation script
import os
import PACKAGE_NAME
path = os.path.dirname(PACKAGE_NAME.__file__)
# copy files to path
```

However I cannot do that. My package import depends on the files being copied to its directory. One thing I maybe can do is this:

```
# another messier post installation approach
import os
# add location of dependencies to system path to allow package import
os.environ['PATH'] += CURRENT_LOCATION_OF_FILES_TO_BE_COPIED
import PACKAGE_NAME
path = os.path.dirname(PACKAGE_NAME.__file__)
# copy files to path
```

Is there a better way to copy files in installation location of a package after running `setup.py` without requiring package import?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do with a package import. The reason your first approach does not work is because the way Python looks for modules/packages. It searches through `sys.path` sequentially, so if you reverse `sys.path` maybe you can do it:

```
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[::-1]
```

It may work but it is kinda hacky though.